# Does Hilbert transform commute with integral?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Suppose $\omega$ is defined on torus $\mathbb{T}$ with mean-zero condition, $\langle\omega\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\omega(\alpha)\mathrm{d}\alpha=0.$

Suppose $h(\alpha)=H\omega(\alpha)=P.V.\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{\omega(\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}\mathrm{d}\beta$ is well-defined on for $\alpha\in\mathbb{T}$.

I was wondering if the Hilbert transform can commute with integration, i.e.,
$\int_{\mathbb{T}}h(\alpha)\mathrm{d}\alpha=\int_{\mathbb{T}}H\omega(\alpha)\mathrm{d}\alpha=H\int_{\mathbb{T}}\omega(\alpha)\mathrm{d}\alpha=0$.

I am not familiar with singular integral operators, and I do not know how to apply Fubini's theorem here.

Comment: $H \omega$ is well-defined means you are assuming $\omega$ is a $1$-periodic distribution defined by its Fourier series $\sum_n c_n e^{2i \pi n x}$ where $c_n$ is bounded by some polynomial $P(n)$ (which means for $\varphi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ : $\langle \omega, \varphi \rangle = \sum_n c_n a_n e^{2i \pi n x}$ which converges, where $a_n=\int_0^1\varphi(x)e^{-2i \pi n x}dx$). Thus $c_n=\langle \omega,e^{-2i\pi n x} \rangle$ is well-defined. Iff $c_n=\langle \omega,1 \rangle =0$ then $H \omega = -i\sum_{n} \text{sign}(n) c_n e^{2i \pi n x}$ and $\langle H\omega, 1\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @reuns: I think that's an answer, more than a comment. Would you mind posting it as such?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I guess the OP doesn't know $1$-periodic distributions and needs a concrete proof for $\omega \in C^0, \langle \omega,1 \rangle = 0$